# Powershell start-process hidden wmplayer file with spaces

Tags: powershell, start-process, wmplayer

`powershell Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' c:\windows\media\notify.wav`
run ok.

`powershell Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' c:\windows\media\windows background.wav`run bad.

`powershell Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' 'c:\windows\media\windows background.wav'`run bad.

`powershell Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\windows\media\windows background.wav"`run bad.

`powershell "& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' 'c:\windows\media\windows background.wav'"` run ok but it's no hidden.

¿How fix the spaces in the arguments, please?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to do it with `wmplayer.exe`? The application will not be visible but it will stay loaded as a process to find in taskmanager or `Get-Process`. The [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) way is more in line with:

```
powershell (New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer('c:\windows\media\Windows Battery Critical.wav')).PlaySync()
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I knew that way and others. She just wanted to know how to put spaces in the argument. `powershell Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' c:\windows\media\notify.wav` run ok but `powershell Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' 'c:\windows\media\windows background.wav'` with spaces run bad.

Comment: Not a problem with [tag:powershell] then. See this for more info on `cmd.exe` [link](https://superuser.com/questions/238810/problem-with-quotes-around-file-names-in-windows-command-shell)

Answer (score 0):

No visible player:

```
powershell (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer 'c:\windows\media\windows background.wav').PlaySync()

powershell $PLAYER = New-Object Media.SoundPlayer; $PLAYER.soundlocation='C:\windows\media\windows background.wav'; $PLAYER.PlaySync()

powershell Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore; $mediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer; $mediaPlayer.open('c:\windows\media\windows background.wav'); $mediaPlayer.Play(); start-sleep 3
```

The sound file does not support spaces: *********************

```
powershell Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' c:\windows\media\notify.wav & timeout 3 >nul & taskkill /f /im wmplayer.exe>nul
```

Visible player:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" "c:\windows\media\windows background.wav" & timeout 3 >nul & taskkill /f /im wmplayer.exe>nul
```

W10:

```
start "" "c:\windows\media\windows background.wav" & timeout 3 >nul & taskkill /f /im music.ui.exe>nul

start "explorer.exe shell:" "c:\windows\media\windows background.wav" & timeout 3 >nul & taskkill /f /im music.ui.exe>nul
```

W11:

```
start "" "c:\windows\media\windows background.wav" & timeout 3 >nul & taskkill /f /im microsoft.media.player.exe>nul

start "explorer.exe shell:" "c:\windows\media\windows background.wav" & timeout 3 >nul & taskkill /f /im microsoft.media.player.exe>nul
```